# Persistence in ArcObjects 10.4 back to IPersistVariant?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.5

In the 9.x versions of ArcGIS Desktop the way to persist data in the MXD was through implementing the IPersistVariant interface. In version 10.0 the advised way to persist data was use of the PersistenceHelperClass.

Now in 10.5 the IPersistVariant is advised again, there is no mention of the PersistenceHelperClass anymore and my code fails. Is this really happening?

Answer (score 2):

ESRI Premium Support Services have confirmed that the PersistenceHelperClass has been deprecated as of AGD10.4.x. Persisting data to the mxd is no longer supported.

Solution is to design something custom to persist object data yourself.